# Git completely remove an unmerged root node

Tags: git

We have two repos, Repo1 and Repo2. It looks like "someone" pushed Repo2 to Repo1/origin and now Repo1 contains both Repo1 and Repo2. There are two seperate root nodes and nothing has been merged (fortunately). Repo1 is also polluted with a whole bunch of tags/branches from Repo2.

How can one completely nuke any commits (and their tags/branches) with a particular ancestor (Repo2's root node aka "Initial commit")? Or perhaps a different/easier way to splice out these two repos?

Note that both repos contain years of work (so not practical to look at each commit manually), however it's practical for everyone using Repo1 to re-clone if need be.

Comment: what is merge strategy used? 
by what command both branches have been combined/pushed?

Comment: There's been no merging. I think just a normal "git push origin" with the wrong origin set somehow but that's just a guess, as it's one of two ways to end up with multiple root nodes and it's definitely not a new orphan branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your text description, I *think* what you meant to say is that you have a single repository with two independent (disjoint, to be technical) sub-graphs of commits within them.  Here, for instance, is a diagram of such a repository:

```
     C--D
    /    \
A--B      G--H   <-- branch1
    \    /
     E--F   <-- branch2

I--J--K--L   <-- master
       \
        M--N   <-- develop
```

This particular graph has four "entry points", namely commits `F` and `H` in the subgraph rooted at `A` and commits `L` and `N` in the subgraph rooted at `I`.

While there's nothing fundamentally wrong with, or broken about, such a repository, it's relatively easy to split this into two separate repositories.  Simply start with two clones, both of which look like this.  (You can use `git clone --mirror` to make mirror clones that keep all refs.  Be sure to erase their `origin`s so that they don't both point back to the original combined repository.)

In one such clone, remove any external labels—branch names, tag names, and other references if any other references exist—to any of the commits in *one* of the two subgraphs:

```
     C--D
    /    \
A--B      G--H   <-- branch1
    \    /
     E--F   <-- branch2

I--J--K--L   [abandoned]
       \
        M--N   [abandoned]
```

Be sure to include any tags or other names that point into the intentionally-abandoned subgraph.  Normal graph-viewing commands, like `git log`, won't show the unreferenced subgraph: it will *appear* to be removed, though it will still be physically present.  Eventually, the unreferenced subgraph will fall away, or you can remove it more quickly using `git gc`.  Clones made *from* this repository won't have the unreferenced subgraph.

In the other of the two clones, remove all references to the *other* subgraph:

```
     C--D
    /    \
A--B      G--H   [abandoned]
    \    /
     E--F   [abandoned]

I--J--K--L   <-- master
       \
        M--N   <-- develop
```

As before, the unreferenced subgraph will eventually fall away.

Note that any clones of the original, two-independent-subgraph repository *can* be used to `git push` to *either* of these split-apart clones.  For that matter, any third, completely-independent repository can *also* be used to push to either of these two clones.  Any push that adds a name for a commit that is in an independent subgraph will cause the entire independent subgraph to go in to the recipient of the push.  [As you surmise in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55184289/git-completely-remove-an-unmerged-root-node#comment97107557_55184289), I suspect that's how this situation arose in the first place.

You can add a pre-receive hook that rejects new names that add a new root commit, though there are no handy pre-receive hooks of this form that I know of.  It's easy to do, but slow: run `git rev-list --all --max-parents=0 --count` to count existing roots, and a second `git rev-list --all --max-parents=0 --count <hash>` to count roots you would have if you accepted a proposed name-to-hash-ID mapping from a `git push`.  If the count increases, the new push adds a new root.

Note that one can add a new root that's *not* part of a disjoint subgraph.  For instance, consider the "before and proposed after" graphs:

```
before:
A--B--C  <-- master

after:

A--B--C--F--G  <-- master
        /
    D--E
```

This kind of pre-receive hook would reject such a push.  That might be what you want, but it might not; be careful what you program for. :-)

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly correct but what I'm kinda hoping for is a one liner that can do this: "In one such clone, remove any external labels—branch names, tag names, and other references if any other references exist—to any of the commits in one of the two subgraphs:". There are plenty of branches/tags and it would be rather painful to have to go through all of them individually. Essentially any command that can get all tags/branches/references (even if that's three commands) "reachable" from a particular commit would help identify what to remove and then maybe pipe that output to a remove.

Comment: `git for-each-ref` can do this (as long as your Git is new enough): `git for-each-ref --contains <root> refs/` gets you one set, and `--no-contains` gets you the other.

Answer (score 0):

Posting this for the TLDR crowd, all credit to torek's excellent answer.

I ran this (on windows MINGW64 git cli, quoting/escaping may vary on other terminals), reviewed it then ran all the commands output by it.

```
git for-each-ref --contains <root_commit_hash> --format="%(refname:short)" refs/tags | xargs -I % echo git tag -d % \&\& git push --delete origin %
```

Add some `git gc` and/or `git prune` for good measure.